Disable to use Woocommerce API for users
I have created a custom checkbox for users to block them from using the Woocommerce API if the box is checked. However, if the box is checked the user can still use the API. The filter and code I'm using:
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_pre_dispatch', 'restrict_api_access_based_on_user_meta', 10, 3);

function restrict_api_access_based_on_user_meta($result, $server, $request) {
    // Check if the request is for the WooCommerce products endpoint
    if (strpos($request->get_route(), '/wc/v3/products') !== false) {
        // Retrieve user ID from the authentication information
        $user_id = apply_filters('determine_current_user', null);
        
        // Check if the user is authenticated and retrieve the 'disable_account_api' meta value
        if ($user_id) {
            $disable_account_api = get_user_meta($user_id, 'disable_account_api', true);

            // If 'disable_account_api' is set to "yes", deny access
            if ($disable_account_api === 'yes') {
                return new WP_Error(
                    'api_disabled',
                    __('API access has been disabled for this account.', 'woocommerce'),
                    array('status' => 403)
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

  

Edit-user.php page


What's the Question?

I have created a custom Checkbox for users . if that checkbox is ticked then user can't use his woocommerce api keys . @gael

Still not a Question. Do you want users to be able to use wc api keys if the checkbox is checked?

Yes we can do that too. if checkbox is checked then user cant use wc api keys.  @gael

do you work with WooCommerce REST API?

Yes i have created api for Users but i dont want to revoke those keys . so i created a custom checkbox for edit user page . when i checked that checkbox  so i want it will not let user to use his API

Note that woocommerce_rest_pre_dispatch hook doesn't exist, only WordPress rest_pre_dispatch hook exist… As WooCommerce Rest API extends WordPress Rest API, you should try using rest_pre_dispatch filter hook instead.
